# How to rotate pages in pdf-to-printer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-modules

I am using [pdf-to-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-to-printer) in node js to make a little webprinter application. This isn't the most used method, but it works decent enough. There is one little thing I don't get:
[image]
Like you can see, the api provides a landscape mode in the options, but it's listed as a string while I'd expect a boolean. Which value do I need to pass through?

Tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that package is using SumatraPDF (Which I Support) via a complex wrapper you may find using SumatraPDF portable from https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/download-free-pdf-viewer.html is quicker and much more reliable to set its options direct where the command to turn pages by 90 degrees is a comma delimited string "landscape" or "portrait" .
NOTE it is best to use current version (which also allows for custom page sizes) when possible https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/prerelease

`SumatraPDF -print-to <printer-name>` [-print-settings "portrait"](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Command-line-arguments) `file(s).pdf`

Note the files do not need to be PDF it will also work with any supported file type like eBooks or HTML and images. However **in all cases the PDF printed by Windows Imaging will be image based** (not text searchable), thus NOT suitable for TEXT flattening of forms, simply converting the static form to imagery.